# Why is my macOS app bypassing sandboxed file access?

Tags: swift, macos, appstore-sandbox

I'm using macOS sandboxing and file path bookmarks for the first time in an app.

One thing that's impeding my understanding is that my app seems to be able to open any folder path, regardless of sandboxing.

For example, I can access the file structure and file contents of the launch daemons path (which I assume would be off limits to a sandboxed app).

This is my app delegate that I've modified from a clean Swift UI / AppKit App Delegate project to showcase this.

```
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

@main
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var window: NSWindow!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Library/LaunchDaemons")
        if let enumerator = FileManager.default.enumerator(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys: [.isRegularFileKey, .isDirectoryKey], options: [.skipsHiddenFiles, .skipsPackageDescendants]) {
            
            for case let fileURL as URL in enumerator {
                print(fileURL);
                do {
                    let contents = try String(contentsOf: fileURL, encoding: .utf8)
                    print(contents)
                } catch {
                    
                }
                
            }
        }
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
}
```

I have set "User Selected File" to `none` in the app's sandbox entitlements.

The file path and file contents are successfully printed to the console.

What am I missing here? Why is this app able to get access to this path?

FYI - I'm just running this in the Xcode debugger.

Comment: What happens in the missing code (Read files)? What does “still able to read it” mean to you?

Comment: Hey matt. In this case, I'm only using the file URLs to create my own file tree UI. I'm not actually opening and reading data from these files (yet). Is reading file system structure ok, but it's the act of actually opening files that sandbox protects? I can try this when I am back at computer to verify myself also.

Comment: At the moment I'm just asking you what the missing code is and what output you are seeing.

Comment: Matt, see my updated code. I created a new Xcode project, and the only changes made are the ones you see there (to the app delegate file). The file path and file contents are successfully printed to the console. My assumption was this should not be possible with a sandboxed app where the user has not explicitly selected this path via an NSOpenPanel.

Comment: Based on what you've said, I'd conjecture that `/Library/LaunchDaemons` just isn't an area your app is locked out of.

Comment: Right. So, for a brand new app in this case, what defines what it is or isn't locked out of? Is it based on user the app is running as? I thought Sandbox was supposed to stop an app from accessing any file path other than those explicitly allowed by the user? Otherwise, wouldn't this basically be more or less equivalent to an app having "Full Disk Access" allowed by default?

Comment: Well try the user Desktop or the user Library.

Comment: Ok, so anything in the users directory is blocked, the enumeration comes back empty. But I can put "/" as the path, and it'll happily start printing file paths and content. So I'm obviously missing something pertinent to the concept of sandboxing here. How come the user level folders/files are blocked, but I can access other files on the filesystem outside of that?

Comment: I guess I need to dive deeper into the documentation.

Comment: "When you adopt App Sandbox, your application has access to the following locations:... Temporary directories, command-line tool directories, and specific world-readable locations. A sandboxed app has varying degrees of access to files in certain other well-defined locations" - https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html

Comment: I suppose this includes those paths I'm seeing.

Comment: Not necessarily. This is still not a code-signed app coming from the app store, so the experiment doesn't really tell us what would happen under those conditions.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the advice. I have also posted this question to the apple developer forum, there may be some extra information there at some point - https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/674485?page=1#663355022

Comment: Cool, thanks for that link. It is asserted in some places that true sandboxing would in fact lock you out of `/Library` but perhaps we are not seeing that condition.

Comment: Yeah at this point I'll just follow the NSOpenPanel / Bookmarking protocol and trust that what we're seeing here is either expected of sandbox or an anomaly. I just wanted to know why is all :)

Comment: I'd like to know that too!